# Want to build list of hyperlinks from dom using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to use JQuery to search through the current document, using the following procedure, only I can't quite figure out the syntax:

1. Make a list of the ID of every DIV where data-role="page" and that contains the text "abcd"
2. Loop through the result of this and create an HTML list:
3. Find the first H1 tag and get its text to use in the hyperlink for each found DIV.
4. Build the LI with the hyperlink: <li><a href="#[THE ID OF THE DIV]"\>[THE TEXT FROM THE H1 TAG]</a></li>
5. Convert the result of all this to an HTML block that gets inserted into a specific DIV.

I'm betting there's a way of doing this with maybe three lines of JQuery.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Post some code if you are having trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you're trying to do, your explanation does make sense, but I agree with the others it'd be nice to see what you've tried so far and then maybe it'd be easier to help... as estshy says, I guess the SO community isn't here to write code for other folks...

...but I was amused by the "maybe three lines of jQuery" and, after all, jQuery can be used to produce some horrendous one-liners...

...so here's a one-liner that does what you want:

```
$("div[data-role='page']").filter(function(i, el) { return $(el).contents().text().indexOf("abcd") != -1}).each(function(i, el) { $("#results").append("<li><a href='#" + $(el).attr("id") + "'>" + $(el).find("h1").first().text() + "</a></li>")})
```

Accompanying fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ya4yt/

This isn't great code, so joking aside, maybe if you like what it does, you can tidy it up a bit for your project.

Comment: I beg to differ. This is actually great code, and with a little tweaking I got what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Splendid! I'm glad it worked for you. I thought you got a bit harshly treated with the downvotes and the 'closed as too broad' - your question made sense to me - I do similar things fairly often (ie, build tables of contents out of my DIVs and H1 etc structures - recent example here: http://simonlikesmaps.appspot.com/#view=HelpView/tab=tab-here

Comment: Thanks again! I would have made it less broad, but that would not have yielded such a useful answer, which you kindly supplied. And now somebody else out there searching for a similar JQuery-based search function will also benefit from your acceptance of the challenge.

Answer (score 0):

To get you started:

```
var idList = []
$("div['data-role'='page']").each(function() {
  idList.push($(this).attr('id');
});
```

Not sure how you want the H1 output and the following html...

Answer (score 0):

You can start with

```
$('div[data-role=page]').each(function(item)
{
    var text = $(item).text();

    if(text.indexOf('abcd') == -1)
    {
        return false;
    }

    /* Now manipulate your divs here */
}
```

> I'm betting there's a way of doing this with maybe three lines of
>   JQuery.

No, there isn't. You have already 8 lines. No one is going to write code for you.